# Forwarding Mail - "New-InboxRule -ForwardTo" vs. "Set-Mailbox -ForwardingSmtpAddress"

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, office365

When looking up how to forward email messages for users,
there are 2 Methods that come up. Create a `New-InboxRule -ForwardTo`, that will forward the emails to another address, or use Powershell and `Set-Mailbox -ForwardingSmtpAddress` to the destination mailbox.

User will need to forward their emails when they are out of the Office for an Extended period of time, more than 4 hours, so we are flooded with requests to do the forwarding. Users can set this up in Out Of Office Rules, but Managers Cannot.

We have always used the `Set-Mailbox -ForwardingSmtpAddress` method in the IT Group. Looking to have an Interface on our Intranet portal for users/managers to do this on their own and have it know who in their team to be able to forward emails to. Intranet Portal is C# Razor pages and for other connections to Exchange Online we use MS Graph API calls.

MS Graph API does not Support `Set-Mailbox -ForwardingSmtpAddress` only `New-InboxRule -ForwardTo`  I know I can work in the Powershell script but would like to keep what we can in MS Graph.

Can someone give a good explanation on the differences between the two methods and why one would be preferred to the other?

Thank you,